# Is it possible to make a curve visible through bevel geometry?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a curve with a round bevel, like so:

[image: Curve + Bevel]

In the Viewport Display option, I have checked "In Front".
I do get the normals in front, but what I expected was to see the actual curve spline as well.

I.e. something like this (I have faked the result here by adding a second bevel-less curve on top of the other.)

[image]

This might be a bug, or is there a reason the normal handles would be drawn in front but not the curve itself?

Thanks,

/S

Comment: Adding a bevel to a curve converts it (dynamically, non-destructively) to a mesh. The actual curve is no longer there - you can test it by loading the object to a geometry nodes setup and investigating the spreadsheet: there will be no splines.

Comment: Ah, ok. Makes sense, thanks.